# How to handle service startup and shutdown events?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using quartz.net as a windows service to schedule my jobs. My jobs are long running and I need to terminate them gracefully if quartz service stops (either someone manually stops/restarts it or windows shutsdown/restarts; it doesn't matter). Is there any Quartz shutdown event which I can handle in my Jobs? Also does Quartz have a startup event which I can handle to set some startup values in my database? I am using c# for my Jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this code-base:

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server

Alot of the work is already done.

You should debug the code.
But ashga is correct.... IScheduler.Shutdown(true) allows for a graceful shut down.  Which means......it will try to finish up any already-running jobs.

If you use Control-Panel to "Stop Service".........it will probably call the graceful method (I'm guessing, I don't know for sure)........so if the graceful-stop ends before the Control-Panel-Service-Shutdown(timeout) occurs....it will go fine.

If the "graceful shutdown" takes longer than the Control-Panel-Service-Shutdown(timeout)....you'll get a windows message akin to "Your service did not shut down in a timely manner".

........

If you're using an in-memory datastore (Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore)...there isn't much you can do on a service-restart.

If you're using an ADO net datastore ("Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX")...then there is some "pick up from where I left off" stuff.......that's a deeper issue to look into.
"Misfire" would be one of the terms to look at.

If you un-gracefully-stop with an in-memory datastore (Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore).....it's basically the same as if you turned the power off on your computer........when it starts again, it won't know about any "state".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling IScheduler.Shutdown(true) when your application shuts down? 
should allow a graceful shutdown :)

Comment: Quartz is running as a service and I have no control over when it shuts down. Its like going in circles, if I don't know Quartz is shutting down how do I know when to call IScheduler.Shutdown(true)?